# Increment a Integer's int value?

Tags: java, class, integer, int

How do I increment a Integer's value in Java? I know I can get the value with intValue, and I can set it with new Integer(int i).

```
playerID.intValue()++;
```

does not seem to work.

Note: PlayerID is a Integer that has been created with:

```
Integer playerID = new Integer(1);
```

Comment: Why are you using Integers instead of ints?

Comment: @naiad For me it's usually because you can't use primitive types as generic arguments in Java.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`Integer` objects are immutable, so you cannot modify the value once they have been created. You will need to create a new `Integer` and replace the existing one.

```
playerID = new Integer(playerID.intValue() + 1);
```

Comment: If you must use a non-primitive int, and you want mutability, you can try commons MutableInt http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html

Comment: thanks, but for some reason it's still not incrementing. Maybe it's a bug in my code...

Comment: @William : As i know, it will be incremented only in method that increment it.

Comment: Don't use Integer's constructor.

Comment: @ColinD: I believe that spelling it out like this makes it easier to see what is actually going on.

Comment: @Grodriguez: Perhaps, though even then I'd suggest `Integer.valueOf(int)`... I don't like the idea of using bad practices in answers at all, it can lead to people thinking they're ok to do. I also think it's useful for the OP to realize that he can use operations he'd use with an `int` with an `Integer` in the same manner.

Comment: @ColinD: "can lead to people thinking they're ok to do so"? I'm sorry, but it **is** OK to use the constructor, even though `Integer.valueOf(int)` is better. The fact that there are better alternatives (where available -- please note that some people is still stuck on pre-1.5 environments for different reasons) does not mean that using the constructor is "bad practice". And I still believe that my answer was clearer the way I wrote it.

Answer (score 52):

As Grodriguez says, `Integer` objects are immutable. The problem here is that you're trying to increment the `int` value of the player ID rather than the ID itself. In Java 5+, you can just write `playerID++`.

As a side note, never ever call `Integer`'s constructor. Take advantage of autoboxing by just assigning `int`s to `Integer`s directly, like `Integer foo = 5`. This will use `Integer.valueOf(int)` transparently, which is superior to the constructor because it doesn't always have to create a new object.

Answer (score 25):

## `AtomicInteger`

Maybe this is of some worth also: there is a Java class called [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

This class has some useful methods like [`addAndGet(int delta)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#addAndGet(int)) or [`incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()) (and their counterparts) which allow you to increment/decrement the value of the same instance. Though the class is designed to be used in the context of [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)), it's also quite useful in other scenarios and probably fits your need.

```
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger( 0 ) ;
…
count.incrementAndGet();  // Ignoring the return value.
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! This is very useful for calling integer by reference.

Answer (score 25):

Java 7 and 8. Increment DOES change the reference, so it references to another Integer object. Look:

```
@Test
public void incInteger()
{
    Integer i = 5;
    Integer iOrig = i;
    ++i; // Same as i = i + 1;
    Assert.assertEquals(6, i.intValue());
    Assert.assertNotEquals(iOrig, i);
}
```

Integer by itself is still immutable.

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer as it demonstrates the `++i` function (on variable `i`; note that you could have wrote `i++` as well) and the `Integer` class immutability (on variable `iOrig`). Most other answers demonstrate only one of the two notions.

Answer (score 8):

Integer objects are immutable. You can't change the value of the integer held by the object itself, but you can just create a new Integer object to hold the result:

```
Integer start = new Integer(5);
Integer end = start + 5; // end == 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

For Java 7, increment operator '++' works on Integers. Below is a tested example

```
    Integer i = new Integer( 12 );
    System.out.println(i); //12
    i = i++;
    System.out.println(i); //13
```

Comment: But be aware that other references to `i = new Integer(12)` will still refer to `12`, not `13`... easy to get tripped up on this one

Comment: yeah thats why you have to reassign the value to the integer object: i = i++

Comment: `i = i++` is not the same as `i++`. Technically, the `++` doesn't really work on integers I'd say as you can't use it by itself without assigning the result to something.

Comment: you don't have to reassign! look:     

        Integer foo = 5;
        Integer bar = foo;
        foo++;      
        System.out.println("foo: " + foo + " bar: " + bar);

outputs:

foo: 6 bar: 5

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try:

```
final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
i.set(1);
i.get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use IntHolder as mutable alternative to Integer. But does it worth?

Answer (score 3):

All the primitive wrapper objects are immutable.

I'm maybe late to the question but I want to add and clarify that when you do `playerID++`, what really happens is something like this:

```
playerID = Integer.valueOf( playerID.intValue() + 1);
```

[Integer.valueOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and **may** cache other values outside of this range.

Comment: playerID = Integer.valueOf(playerID.intValue() + 1);

A new Integer object is *not* always created.

The autoboxing spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Since Java 7, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1 also applies to the ++ operator

Comment: Got it, answer edited. Incrementing the Integer object `playerID++` results in something like `playerID = Integer.valueOf( playerID.intValue() + 1)` and according to the method's docs: This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

After Java 8, we can use as below

```
import java.lang.Math;
Math.incrementExact(playerID);
//it increment the integer value to + 1. It is also available for long
```