# How do I update the long value of java.lang.Long in Java?

Tags: java

I'm passing in a java.lang.Long class instance to a method (obviously as reference), and I'm wondering whether it's possible to modify its long value so that the caller can get the modified value. I've looked at the documentation for java.lang.Long, but there doesn't seem to exist any setter method for this type. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can not change** Long value. Its immutable.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208943/how-to-increment-a-class-integer-references-value-in-java-from-another-method) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815173/increment-a-integers-int-value) for more info

Comment: Well not without hacking the VM via native code or reflection at any rate. Which of course is an EXTREMELY BAD IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

[java.lang.Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) is a **immutable**, the only way is to reassign the modified value to the previous reference.

```
public Long someMethod(Long l) {
    l = watever;
    return l;
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    Long l = 22235637334634263464L;
    l = someMethod(l);
}
```

Comment: @Chris but Long is final and immutable isn't it?

Comment: @Chris ahh i see, i edited it now. that was not my intention though  :)

Answer (score 1):

Long is immutable in Java. You can change it inside a method in the following way:

1. Wrap it
2. Use AtomicLong
3. Return changed value and reasign it outside the method