# Transferring Integers from one class to another

Tags: java

I have the following problem:

In my main class I have these lines:

```
Integer i;

update.addActionListener(new RewardUpdater(this));

if (argument) {
    i++;
}
```

And in the class RewardUpdater I have this:

```
int i;
this.i = frame.i;

rewardButtonAddition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            updateCenterPanel.removeAll();
            c.repaint();
            text.setText("Test: " + i);
            c.add(beschriftung);
            updateCenterPanel.add(additionReward1);
            updateCenterPanel.add(additionReward2);
            updateCenterPanel.add(additionReward3);

        }
    });
```

But no matter how often I fullfill the if iteration for i++;

My i always gets printed out as 0.

Sorry for the limited code, the whole thing is pretty messy and I tried to only put the necessary things here. If more is needed, I can provide it.

Thanks for a short and fast answer!

Sincerly
Moritz

Comment: where is `i` initialized?

Comment: not sure what you mean by initialized (am fairly new to programming sorry :/)

Comment: Why "Integer" instead of "int" - take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815173/increment-a-integers-int-value

Comment: yea, the naming of the variables is "unlucky", and a little "scope" is missing, but to give it a try: replace `"Test: " + i` by `"Test: "+frame.i` ... how does that behave?

Comment: @ racraman a friend advised me to @xerx693 doesnt change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `Action` (for example `JButton` click) to increment the value you can just add `i++` inside the `ActionListener`.

If on the other hand you want to increment the value somewhere else I would advise to create a new class like so:

```
public class RewardValue {
  private int value;

  public RewardValue(int startValue) {
    this.value = startValue;
  }

  public void increment() {
    value++;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

You can then go on to create a `RewardValue` and pass it around to where you need it. You basically exchange your `i` with `RewardValue`. The public method `increment` should be called at the place where you have `i++`. The public method `get` is there so you can read the value of your new `i`. A small example would look like this:

```
public class MainClass {
  private final RewardValue rewardValue = new RewardValue(0);

  public MainClass() {
    //initiate update 
    //...

    update.addActionListener(new RewardUpdater(rewardValue));

    //of cause the next lines don't need to be in the constructor
    if (argument) {
      rewardUpdater.increment();
    }
  }
}

public class RewardUpdater implements ActionListener {
  private final RewardValue rewardValue;

  public RewardUpdater(RewardValue rewardValue) {
    this.rewardValue = rewardValue;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(AcionEvent e) {
    //... the other lines
    text.setText("Test: "+rewardValue.get());
    // ... the other lines
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. As I am fairly new to programming I haven't quiet caught up with your code. I do not know what increment does or what final is used for. Neither do I fully understand the     `getValue()`. I will try to implement it as good as I can though, thanks alot!

Comment: P.S: I get an error when I create the class RewardValue, like you advised to.         `public void getValue() {
        return value;
      }`             It tells me to change    `void` to     `int`.

Comment: Oops yeah that should be int and not void. If you don't program for that long final is not that important, i'm just so used to using it. I'll edit my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `actionPerformed`method is where you should get the value of i from the frame. Otherwise, the value is obtained from the frame only once, when the listener is constructed, and never changes.

So, in short, replace

```
text.setText("Test: " + i);
```

by

```
text.setText("Test: " + frame.i);
```

and remove the useless `i` field from `RewardUpdater`.

Comment: Then post a minimal reproducible test case. It's hard to say exactly what's wrong with the incomplete code you posted.