# Why java.util.Map value can increment primitive array but not single Integer

Tags: java, collections

Here are three examples:

**Example 1:**

```
int j[] = new int[]{2,2,2,2};
HashMap<Integer, int[]> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put(5,j);
m.get(5)[2]++; // NO COMPAILATION ERROR
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.get(5))); // op: [2, 2, 3, 2]
```

**Example 2:**

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> n = new HashMap<>();
n.put(6, 2);
n.get(6)++; // COMPILATION ERROR - Variable Expected
```

**Example 3:**

```
 HashMap n = new HashMap();
 n.put(6, 2);
 n.get(6)++; // COMPILATION ERROR - Variable Expected
```

The value on a primitive int array can be mutated by just using the increment operator whereas the a Map with actual Integer (Ex 2,3) refuses this with a compilation error, why is that?

Note: I'm expected Example 2 to increment the value in the map. Just as in the below behaviour:

```
Integer x = 2; 
x++;
```

Comment: This is clearly specified in the Java Language Specification. Would a quote from the specification answer your question, or are you looking for a "deeper" reason? If so, please clarify what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @Sweeper I have added the note at the end of the question to clarify what I'm expecting. It's not for functional solution but to understand the language better so both would be good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment a Integer's int value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815173/increment-a-integers-int-value)

Comment: @user207421 The `Integer` class is certainly `final`, but that's not why it can't be incremented.

Comment: @saka1029 `s/final/immutable/`. Java's lack of proper `const`ness can cause temporary terminology amnesia.

Comment: Maps dont hold variables but values, therfore it cannot be assigned to. Incrementation is "add one and assign" operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [JLS §15.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.1),

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result denotes one of three things:
>
> - A variable (in C, this would be called an lvalue)
> - A value
> - Nothing (the expression is said to be void)

And [§15.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) says:

> **15.14.2. Postfix Increment Operator `++`**
>
> A postfix expression followed by a `++` operator is a postfix increment expression.
>
> **The result of the postfix expression must be a variable of a type that is convertible to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.**

The important part is that the expression before the `++` must be a "*variable*", not a "value" or "nothing".

The method invocation expression `m.get(6)` denotes a "value", whereas `m.get(5)[2]` denotes a "variable". This is specified in [§15.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3):

> The result of an array access expression is a *variable* of type `T`, namely the variable within the array selected by the value of the index expression.

On the other hand, in [§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), where method invocation expressions are specified, it does not say that method invocation expressions are variables.

If you think about it, method calls *have* to be values and not variables Imagine if method calls produce variables and you had a method like:

```
public static int foo() {
    return 1;
}
```

And you did:

```
foo()++;
```

What would you be incrementing? The constant `1`? Does `1` actually mean `2` now? That doesn't make much sense, does it?